# How to run WPF/Windows Form on a Web browser?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to run WPF/Windows form on a web Browser. As we already know that WPF/Windows forms are made to run on windows desktop. While Web forms are design to run on a web browser. But Web forms cann't give the functionality , the UI Designing as same as the windows form. That's why I want to run the windows form into web browser.

I have tried it by running it on using different tools and technology like silverlight(which is not presently supported by Microsoft), then I used WinFlector Server to run windows form on web but it is also not showing any result, then I tried by taking two forms like one is web form and another one is windows form on the same project but they both are running separately one on web and another on windows. So basically the main issue is that the main winforms is not running on web browser. I have tried XBPA Form also but it is showing a security issue

Comment: No can do. Web browsers can't somehow run native Windows applications (and it would be a huge security hole if they tried). This isn't a "problem", you're just expecting the impossible

Comment: What's the reason you want it to run in a Web browser and not as stand-alone desktop app?

Comment: Just for fun: You COULD have used the Silverlight browserplugin to host Wpf applications, but it's no longer supported. in any browser Pages designed for Silverlight, was written using the same Xaml as Wpf. :-)

Comment: @KlausGütter do you genuinely not see the value in that? Microsoft often says the same thing, as though they don't know why we would want to do this, and honestly I don't understand why people don't understand why this would be so valuable.

Comment: @Just: Converting a desktop application to a web application is a huge undertaking, and there are some things you just cannot do in a web application.

Comment: Depending on what your exact needs are, using ClickOnce as a means of distributing the app via the web could be useful for you? It won't "run in the browser", but in some aspects it resembles running an app "kind of online".

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's not worth getting into an extended argument over IMO, but I just want to say I think that viewpoint (some things just can't be done on the web) is a bit dated. Of course it's literally true, but as a practical matter I can't think of many desktop applications still relevant in 2023 that in principle can't have most, if not all, of their useful functionality made available on the web.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot directly run WPF or Forms code in a web browser. The closest thing that once existed was SilverLight - though it was not strictly 100% drop and go from WPF, it was close - but that has been deprecated and will not run in a modern browser.

There have been efforts to replicate Silverlight or something like it using Webassembly. You might look into [OpenSilver](https://opensilver.net/). They [claim](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/10/17/opensilver-1-1.aspx) it's very close to "source parity" with the original though I can't speak from experience.

Then of course there is [Uno](https://platform.uno/) which strives to do the same for WinUI 3.

(Neither platform is affiliated with Microsoft, or with me).

Having successfully ported an application from WPF to the web using a combination of .NET Blazor and React, I can offer my opinion that anything that attempts to replicate WPF/Silverlight/WinUI 1:1 on the web using anything based on the WASM Mono SDK (which includes Blazor) suffers from pretty unavoidable performance and scalability issues because those platforms do 100% of their rendering and layout themselves rather than leverage the browser itself as a compositing engine. I and others have tried for many years to get Microsoft to bite on the idea of a web-based MAUI target or something along those lines, but to no avail.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Uno.  It's too difficult to get a good compile with it.